# SQL - Get elements from two tables, with a third table with all the rows

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am currently trying to create a SQL statement that allows me to retrieve information from two tables, with a third one which has the `post_id` from each table and the type. This will allow me to know which table the `post_id` is from.

ALL_POSTS:

```
id PRIMARY KEY,
post_id (FOREIGN KEY)
type
```

MOVIES:

```
post_id
type
title
```

MUSIC:

```
post_id
type
title
band
```

This is the SQL statement I used:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* FROM ALL_POSTS as a, MOVIES as b, MUSIC as c WHERE (a.post_id = b.id AND a.type = b.type) OR (a.post_id = c.id AND a.type = c.type)
```

The problem is that it retrieves a lot of results, and all of them are from the MUSIC table, and most of them are repeated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a small set of sample data, and the result you expect when querying that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a **LEFT JOIN** on both tables. This way, it would return all the rows on the **ALL_POSTS** table and the corresponding details on the **MOVIES** and **MUSIC** table.

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_POSTS AS A
    LEFT JOIN MOVIES AS B ON A.post_id = B.post_id AND A.type = B.type
    LEFT JOIN MUSIC AS C ON A.post_id = B.post_id AND A.type = C.type
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are generating a cartesian product from the three tables. Use `JOIN`s instead:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, C.* FROM ALL_POSTS AS A
LEFT JOIN MOVIES AS B ON A.post_id = B.ID AND A.type = B.type
LEFT JOIN MUSIC AS c ON A.post_id = C.ID AND A.type = C.type
```